# Convert from MySQL++ to PostgreSQL at run time

Tags: postgresql, mysql++

I am a recent graduate and have recently joined my job. I have been asked to create a Data Access Layer between the C++ application and the database it is interacting with. The program currently uses simple queries like

1. select 'column' from 'some table' where 'something = something AND something = something'
2. delete 'column' from 'some table' where 'something' = something'
3. update 'something'

There are no joins anywhere, and these are the only three queries used in the application.  I also have to convert it to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Removed TSQL question: one question per post, please.  Also, it wasn't clear what you were asking for.  The literal answer to "is there any thing called tsql" is "yes".  If you need to know more, see Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSQL), then post a separate question if you need to know more.

Answer (score 2):

I assume MySQL++ comes into this because the program already uses it?  If so, I see two ways to proceed:

1. Drop MySQL and MySQL++, and use some other totally different PostgreSQL compatible access library.  This is fine if you plan on making the shift to PostgreSQL permanent, with a single catastrophic cutover.
2. If you need to support MySQL for some time to come, or be able to switch back and forth at will:

   - Find some other library that supports both databases.  I've heard of a few, but never used them, so I can't offer recommendations or advice.
   - You could start work on the v4.0 database independence plan in the [MySQL++ Wishlist](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/mysqlpp/trunk/Wishlist?view=markup).  The plan sketched out there should be pretty clear.  It's a lot of work and makes big changes to the MySQL++ library ABI, which is why it's scheduled for sometime in the vague far future.